# Run function for visibles sheets only

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to run function only for visible sheet.
The code below works in this way but starts to show hidden sheet while I want to let it hidden. How let the sheet hidden ?
Thanks for your help !

```
function loopTest() {

var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('VFX');
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(classeur);

   //Test is sheet is not hidden
   if (ss.isSheetHidden()!= true) {

   //if not hidden run some code  
     var range = ss.getRange("D14:D"); // Range that gets modified, and has a value in to trigger formatting.
  range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex(); // Added

   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0]) { // Modified
      ss.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":Q" + (i + offsetRow)) //Range to get formated
      .setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, "#eFEfeF", 
       SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID) // Modified
    ;
    } else {
      ss.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":Q" + (i + offsetRow)) //Range to get formated
      .setBorder(false, null, null, null, null, null, "efefef", 
                    SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
      ;
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I meant if you don't want to make your sheet active then don't activate it, does it make sense? Script can run on hidden sheet, that's guaranteed.

Comment: Sorry, I just start with Apps Script and I finally understood what you meant. I removed ss function replaced by classeur and It works ! Thank you Kos 